# Android dynamic views generated with grey color. Can't change radiobutton color

Tags: android, xml, colors, radio-button, view

I'm generating dynamicaly a Test based questionary.

The generated views are shown with a kind of grey color, that makes them near invisible. I can change the color of the textViews and the problem is solved, but I can't change the color of the circle from the radioButton.

I don't know why it's not the same color as the xml radioButtons.

Here is my code:

```
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.loaded_exercice);
           Context tContext=getApplicationContext();
           for (int i=0;i<t.getPreguntes().length;i++){
                   TextView tv = new TextView(tContext);
                   tv.setText(t.getPreguntes()[i].getFrase());
                   tv.setTextSize(20);
                   tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                   layout.addView(tv);
                   RadioGroup RG=new RadioGroup(tContext);
                   for (int j=0;j<t.getPreguntes()[i].getRespostes().length;j++){
                           RadioButton tv2 = new RadioButton(tContext);
                           tv2.setAlpha(1.0f);
                           tv2.setText(t.getPreguntes()[i].getRespostes()[j].getResposta());
                           tv2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                           RG.addView(tv2);   
                   }
                   RG.setAlpha(1.0f);
                   layout.addView(RG);
           }
```

Does anyone know how to easily change the color of the circle or make the generated views shown with a "normal" color?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are You applying any theme in xml to radiobuttons?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just not using the Context and create all the views like this one:

```
                       RadioButton tv2 = new RadioButton(this);
```

Just replacing **tContext** for **this**